# In what format should I store cart data in the local storage

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, frontend, shopping-cart

I am developing a shopping cart website using Spring Boot 2 and Angular 6, and one of the prerequisite is to allow users to add products to their shopping cart even when they are not authenticated. To reach this goal, I save the added products into the local storage of the user's browser as json objects, as you can see from the image below.

[image]

When the user logs in, this data is merge into the database table which stores authenticated user cart data, alongside other of his data.

To manage the web storage I use the library **ngx-webstorage**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-webstorage

I wrote a typescript class to manage the storage, which I provide below:

```
@Injectable()
export class LocalStorageHelper {

    constructor(private localStorageService: LocalStorageService) { }

    /**
     * Creates an empty cart if no one already exists and returns it.
     */
    private createCart(): Cart {
        const cart = new Cart(1, 0, []);
        this.localStorageService.store('cart', this.toJSONString(cart));
        return cart;
    }

    /**
     * Clears the cart (i.e., when the user logs in successfully).
     */
    public clearCart(): void {
        this.localStorageService.clear('cart');
    }

    public saveCart(cart: Cart): Cart {
        this.localStorageService.store('cart', this.toJSONString(cart));
        return cart;
    }

    /**
     * Converts the local storage cart content into a Cart object for further processing.
     */
    public getCart(): Cart {
        let cart: Cart = this.toJSONObject(this.localStorageService.retrieve('cart'));
        if (cart === null) {
            cart = this.createCart();
        }
        return cart;
    }

    /**
     * Adds a product to the cart, by first, it checks whether that product already exists.
     *
     * @param product the product being added.
     */
    public addToCart(product: Product): Cart {
        const cart = this.getCart();
        const item = cart.items.find(i => i.product.id === product.id);
        if (item === undefined) {
            cart.items.push(new CartItem(1, product.price, product));
        } else {
            item.quantity += 1;
            item.totalAmount += product.price;
        }
        cart.totalAmount += product.price;
        return this.saveCart(cart);
    }

    /**
     * Drops an item from the cart.
     *
     * @param productId id of the product being dropped from the cart.
     */
    public dropFromCart(productId: number): Cart {
        const cart = this.getCart();
        const item = cart.items.find(i => i.product.id === productId);
        if (item !== undefined) {
            cart.totalAmount -= item.totalAmount;
            cart.items.splice(cart.items.indexOf(item, 0), 1);
        }
        return this.saveCart(cart);
    }

    /**
     * Updates the quantity of a product by one with the given one.
     *
     * @param productId id of the product whose quantity is gonna be updated.
     * @param productQty quantity of the product being updated (should be greater than 0).
     */
    public updateItemQuantity(productId: number, productQty: number): Cart {
        if (productQty < 1) {
            return;
        }
        const cart = this.getCart();
        const item = cart.items.find(i => i.product.id === productId);
        if (item !== undefined) {
            const deltaAmount = CartUtil.calculateDeltaAmount(item, productQty);
            item.quantity = productQty;
            item.totalAmount = productQty * item.product.price;
            cart.totalAmount += deltaAmount;
        }
        return this.saveCart(cart);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a string to a JSON.
     *
     * @param value the string being converted.
     */
    private toJSONObject(value: string): any {
        return JSON.parse(value);
    }

    /**
     * Converts a JSON object to a string.
     *
     * @param value the JSOn object being converted.
     */
    private toJSONString(value: any): string {
        return JSON.stringify(value);
    }
}
```

What I don't like of this solution is that those data are exposed in clear while other websites online provide a hash, i.e.

[image]

So my doubt is about what format to use to store cart content into the local storage. Is it fine how I am doing it now, or is there a better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should store the cart's content locally on the user's machine. It can easily get out of sync when a product changes on the server (eg. the price gets updated).

I would suggest you to create an anonymous cart on the server and only store the cart's identifier. I believe this is the hash you're referring to when mentioning other solutions.

Having the cart stored on the server will give you some other benefits as well—other than the state sync, eg. you'll be able to track carts abandonment.